# How to put range of ints instead writing them one by one kotlin listOf

Tags: kotlin

For example we have such array:

```
val listArr = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

and finally we receive:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

maybe it is possible to write something like that:

```
val listArr = listOf(1..7)
```

and receive similar result. Or it is impossible right now?

Comment: `val listArr = (1..7).toList()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [IntRange.toList()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/) function:

```
val list = (1..7).toList()
```

Ranges are automatically converted to lists when concatenating:

```
val combined = (1..6) + 12 + (34..37)
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 34, 35, 36, 37]
```

Comment: but how we can use such solution in another list for example 1,2,3,4,5,6,12,34,35,36,37 so here we can put two ranges from your solution?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, when adding a number, list or range to a range, the result is a list with all values concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

RobCo's answer is correct and answers the question asked.

About the followup question you asked in the comment to his answer:

> how we can use such solution in another list for example 1,2,3,4,5,6,12,34,35,36,37

You could write a new function that accepts ranges:

```
fun customListOf(vararg ranges: IntRange) = ranges.flatMap { it.toList() }
```

Then use it like this:

```
fun main() {
    val list = customListOf(1..6, 12..12, 34..37)
    println(list)
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 34, 35, 36, 37]
```

However, you need to pass a range even for a single value like `12..12` above.

---

If you wanted to be hacky, you could write a function that accepts a `vararg range: Any`, and use reflection to check the type at runtime. That would allow you to mix ranges and ints in the same call:

```
fun hackyCustomListOf(vararg rangeOrInt: Any) = rangeOrInt.flatMap {
    when (it) {
        is IntRange -> it.toList()
        is Int -> listOf(it)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Expected an IntRange or an Int, got ${it::class}")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
fun main() {
    val list1 = hackyCustomListOf(1, 5, 12..15, 25, 99..102)
    println(list1)
    val list2 = hackyCustomListOf(1..3, "boom", 5.0)
    println(list2)
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 25, 99, 100, 101, 102]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected an IntRange or an Int, got class kotlin.String
    at TestKt.hackyCustomListOf(test.kt:7)
    at TestKt.main(test.kt:14)
    at TestKt.main(test.kt)
```

This removes compile-time checks on the argument, so I don't think it's a good idea. Fun exercise, though.